What is meant by damnable heresies in 2 Peter 2:1

“But there were false prophets also among the people, even as there shall be false teachers among you, who privily shall bring in damnable heresies, even denying the Lord that bought them, and bring upon themselves swift destruction.”
‭‭2 Peter‬ ‭2‬:‭1‬ ‭

How do these damnable heresies differ from heresies or do they?
And damnable meaning eternally or just in this life?
Are not all heresies damnable?

The problem arises from relying on a single translation (the KJV) rather than comparing several different versions. The NKJV and almost all other translations don't use the inappropriate word "damnable".

@ray case and point

There are 2 important words:

Heresy. According to Thayer's Greek Lexicon:
STRONGS NT 139: αἵρεσις

that which is chosen, a chosen course of thought and action; hence one's chosen opinion, tenet; according to the context, an opinion varying from the true exposition of the Christian faith (heresy): 2 Peter 2:1 (cf. DeWette at the passage), and in ecclesiastical writings (cf. Sophocles' Lexicon, under the word).

Destructive (damnable). According to Thayer's Greek Lexicon:
STRONGS NT 684: ἀπώλεια

passively, a perishing, ruin, destruction;
a. in general: τό ἀργύριον σου σύν σοι εἴη εἰς ἀπώλειαν, let thy money perish with thee, Acts 8:20; βυρθίζειν τινα εἰς ὄλεθρον καί ἀπώλειαν, with the included idea of misery, 1 Timothy 6:9; αἱρέσεις ἀπωλείας destructive opinions, 2 Peter 2:1; ἐπάγειν ἑαυτοῖς ἀπώλειαν, ibid. cf. 2 Peter 2:3.


Most translations translate it as "destructive". What is being referred to are destructive doctrines that lead people astray from the true teachings of Christianity. They deny the fundamental truths of the gospel.
What do we know:

All heresies are dangerous
Not all heresies are equally damaging (that is, spiritually corrupting)

1 Corinthians 3:12-15

Now if anyone builds on the foundation with gold, silver, precious
stones, wood, hay, straw— each one's work will become manifest, for
the Day will disclose it, because it will be revealed by fire, and the
fire will test what sort of work each one has done. If the work
that anyone has built on the foundation survives, he will receive a
reward. If anyone's work is burned up, he will suffer loss, though
he himself will be saved, but only as through fire.

"Destructive" as used here, indicates a higher level of danger, as it notes:  bring upon themselves swift destruction. So, we can say that these teachings can lead to ruin, both in this life and potentially eternally if one does not repent.

And, of course, the passage itself provides an example of such a heresy: "denying the Lord that bought them".

To add specificity to the false teachings addressed, let me add the following:
There were “only” three prominent heresies that emerged during the time the New Testament was being completed. Briefly, they were
•   Judaizers taught that the true followers of Jesus also need to follow the 613 laws of Torah.
•   Nicolaitans taught that since all sins are forgiven, so indulge in anything you like without restraint.
•   False prophets and Gnostics: Blended philosophy, speculations, other beliefs, and other values into Christianity.
As Jesus warned his disciples . . .

“Beware of false prophets, who come to you in sheep's clothing but
inwardly are ravenous wolves. You will recognize them by their fruits.
Are grapes gathered from thornbushes, or figs from thistles?” –
Matthew 7:15, 16 ESV

And Paul also warned the believers . . .

“I know that after my departure fierce wolves will come in among you,
not sparing the flock.” – Acts 20:29 ESV

Nicolaitans
The name of the sect called Nicolaitans was started by a man named Nicolas of Antioch, who had been appointed a deacon by the apostles in Acts 6:5. However, what he later taught was in direct conflict with the letter that the Apostles and elders in Jerusalem wrote to the Gentile believers in Antioch, Syria, and Cilicia that was delivered by Paul, Barnabas, Judas Barsabbas, and Silas. It’s generally believed that the Council at Jerusalem was held ca. 48-50 AD and the letter delivered soon after. Here’s what they wrote in the letter according to Acts 15:23-29 ESV.

“The brothers, both the apostles and the elders, to the brothers who
are of the Gentiles in Antioch and Syria and Cilicia, greetings. Since
we have heard that some persons have gone out from us and troubled you
with words, unsettling your minds, although we gave them no
instructions, it has seemed good to us, having come to one accord, to
choose men and send them to you with our beloved Barnabas and Paul,
men who have risked their lives for the name of our Lord Jesus Christ.
We have therefore sent Judas and Silas, who themselves will tell you
the same things by word of mouth. For it has seemed good to the Holy
Spirit and to us to lay on you no greater burden than these
requirements: that you abstain from what has been sacrificed to idols,
and from blood, and from what has been strangled, and from sexual
immorality. If you keep yourselves from these, you will do well.
Farewell.”

The following description of the Nicolaitans was written by Ireneus, who was the bishop of Lugdunum, the present city of Lyons, France. The following quote comes from his book, Against Heresies, written very early in church history, about 180 AD.

“The Nicolaitanes are the followers of that Nicolas who was one of the
seven first ordained to the diaconate by the apostles. They lead lives
of unrestrained indulgence. The character of these men is very plainly
pointed out in the Apocalypse of John, [when they are represented] as
teaching that it is a matter of indifference to practise adultery, and
to eat things sacrificed to idols. Wherefore the Word has also spoken
of them thus: But this you have, that you hate the deeds of the
Nicolaitanes, which I also hate.” – Ireneus (ca. 130 - ca. 202 AD),
Against Heresies, Book I, Chapter 26, Doctrines of Cerinthus, the
Ebionites, and Nicolaitans

A reference to people practicing what the Nicolaitans taught is found in both in 2 Peter 2 (commonly dated 65-68 AD) and in Jude (commonly dated to about 65 AD).

They are blots and blemishes, reveling in their deceptions, while they
feast with you. They have eyes full of adultery, insatiable for sin.
They entice unsteady souls. They have hearts trained in greed.
Accursed children! Forsaking the right way, they have gone astray.
They have followed the way of Balaam, the son of Beor, who loved gain
from wrongdoing . . . For, speaking loud boasts of folly, they entice
by sensual passions of the flesh those who are barely escaping from
those who live in error. They promise them freedom, but they
themselves are slaves of corruption. For whatever overcomes a person,
to that he is enslaved.  – 2 Peter 2:13b-15, 18, 19 ESV


For certain people have crept in unnoticed who long ago were
designated for this condemnation, ungodly people, who pervert the
grace of our God into sensuality and deny our only Master and Lord,
Jesus Christ . . . Woe to them! For they walked in the way of Cain and
abandoned themselves for the sake of gain to Balaam's error and
perished in Korah's rebellion. These are hidden reefs at your love
feasts, as they feast with you without fear, shepherds feeding
themselves . . . These are grumblers, malcontents, following their own
sinful desires; they are loud-mouthed boasters, showing favoritism to
gain advantage. – Jude 4, 11, 12a, 16 ESV

In Revelation 2, Jesus commended the Ephesians for their hating the deeds of the Nicolaitans, which Jesus said that he also hates.
In summary from all these sources, the Nicolaitans promoted the following:
•   Motivated by money—as was Balaam
•   Permitted sexual immorality
•   Promoted idols, rituals, and superstitions
•   Taught things not found in the Bible
•   Denied and disowned the Messiah Jesus as our only Master and Lord
Their general behavior was arrogant, self-righteous, and manipulative.
Gnostics
The term Gnostic is derived from the Greek word, gnosis, meaning "applied knowledge." Gnostics taught that secret mystical knowledge from Jesus, the apostles, and others provides the key to enlightenment and salvation.
They wrote and presumably sold books with titles such as “The Secret Teachings of Jesus” and “The Gospel of Judas.” Included in their teachings were a blended jumble of Greek and Zoroastrian mythologies merged with Christianity.
For example, Jesus and the Holy Spirit were supposedly two of seven primary god-like “Aeons” who were able to help humanity transcend the corrupt physical world controlled by “Archons,” one of which was the God of the Old Testament, into the perfect spiritual world in a different dimension of reality by reaching a perfect state of Gnosis. The starting texts you’ll need plus personal coaching can all be yours for the low, low price of $$$ . . .
While these false teachings emerged from the beginning, similar false teachings continued to reappear regularly throughout church history, leading many people astray. So yes, these false prophets and teachers were indeed destructive to many lives. They still are.
